# Create a random GUID in C# within a specified interval

Tags: c#, guid

Using the .NET Framework, is there a way to create a random GUID in C# within a specified interval? For example, I need a random GUID that is greater than ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-1fffffffffffff and less than ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-2fffffffffffff.

Comment: What if you need to generate more GUIDs than are in the range? E.g Your algorithm is called 20 times for the range ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-fffffffffffff0 to ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffffff?

Comment: That's sort of not how they work, generally. There is some non-random element to it, but for versioning reasons and such, you can't just (with random GUIDs) generate one in a particular range. Otherwise they wouldn't work like they do.

Answer (score 7):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx22893a.aspx):

```
[CLSCompliantAttribute(false)]
public Guid(
    uint a,
    ushort b,
    ushort c,
    byte d,
    byte e,
    byte f,
    byte g,
    byte h,
    byte i,
    byte j,
    byte k
)
```

`Guid(0xa,0xb,0xc,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` creates a Guid that corresponds to:

```
0000000a-000b-000c-0001-020304050607
```

You can randomize the parameters any way you like.  For example, you can do:

```
var r[] = new byte[] { 1,2,3,4 } // chosen by fair dice rolls
                                 // guaranteed to be random

var guid = new GUID(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]...
```

Well, you get the idea.  You have to do some bit twiddling to get the fifth parameter right.

Comment: Although this might be stating the obvious, just because it's a `Guid` doesn't mean it's a GUID. That is, it's up to you to make sure your algorithm ensures global uniqueness. Otherwise it's just an `Id`.